# Materialized View Refresh with changing synonym pointer in SQL

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, synonym

I have two tables, `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`.  Then we have a synonym called `TABLE` that points to either `TABLE_1` or `TABLE_2`.  When `TABLE_1` is active, an ETL populates `TABLE_2` and when the run is complete, it switches the `TABLE` synonym to `TABLE_2` to make it the active table.  Then I have a materialized view that does something like this as the SQL:  `select * from TABLE`.  What I am seeing happen is that after the materialize view runs the first time, it caches the actual table the synonym is pointing too.  So when the ETL runs and flips the synonym to point at `TABLE_2`, when a complete refresh is done on the materialized view, it still thinks the synonym is pointed at `TABLE_1`.  Why when I do a complete refresh does the materialized view not pick up the new synonym pointer to `TABLE_2`?

Comment: why do you do this at all? It is so meaningless in my opinion

Comment: When you are loading large datasets, and want to be able to revert tables in the case of bad data, you can use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround to Oracle's bug:

```
alter materialized view MV_NAME nocache;
BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( MV_NAME,'C'); end;
alter materialized view MV_NAME cache;
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything useful in Oracle documentation but just enable the logic:

1. I firstly create materialized view
2. In reality to support this materialized view Oracle makes the `TABLE` with some specific structure (dependent on your query structure) and the rule to refresh the table (as far as I remember it is called `SUMMARY`, but the name does not play any role here)
3. I change synonym target to the table which has another structure
4. The new target table is not "fitting" to the previous structure (e.g. it has totally different amount/data types of columns), the previous structure is invalid then and not working anymore. The underground table must be recreated then.

That's why I would say it is the only way to prevent the errors: reference the real target instead of synonym for creating materialized view.

So, **the answer is**: because the materialized view is a static table-like object dependent on the data set it is selecting; that's why to prevent the inconsistencies materialized view references the real object.

Sometimes I really wonder how many details Oracle hides inside.